# Data Alignment while loading in Cache

Tags: c++, c, caching, memory-alignment

Assuming natural alignment of 4 byte.

```
struct Node
{
int data;
char c_data;
};
int main() {
int global = 10;
struct Node N;
for ( register int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
cout << global << N.data << endl; }
```

if the cache Line size is 16 byte and if my program is accessing these 2 variables in loop, how will these variables be present in cache? assume everything else is register variables.

On Same cache line?

On Different cache line?

If same cache lines, will each member start at 4 byte aligned address in cache? like global variable will span from [0,3] and N will span from [4,7]..something like that? OR if the structure just had a char, it can even start from [5] in cacheline.

Basically, while loading the data in cache, is alignment taken into consideration based on the size of the structure OR it's first member?

Comment: Data are loaded in cache lines based on the line size, not on the data size, so, data organization/alignment in memory is reflected to cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the cache is used depends mostly on the code, that is the theoretical loop that you mention in your question but didn't post. Other variables used before the loop may take precedence, depending on what variable that is allocated where. It is very hard to tell exactly what will happen even if given a detailed source code with a specific system in mind.

Variables that are allocated adjacently in memory are cache-friendly. Basically there should be a chunk of adjacently allocated variables that can get transferred from RAM to cache in order for the cache to be efficient. If you have variables in completely different segments, that will give "cache misses": that is, something will have to get tossed out from the cache and something else has to be read from RAM instead.

For example if you have a chunk of local, stack-allocated variables, it might be beneficial for them all to get stored in cache.

In your case, `global` is allocated in the `.data` section of the memory and `N` is allocated in `.bss` section, so they are not at all adjacent and won't get loaded into the same cache line for that reason. Meaning that in your case, the whole cache discussion is not even applicable.

If you instead had written `struct Node N = {1};`, then it seems reasonable to assume that the variables, if used in the same place in the code, would end up allocated like this in `.data` (I'm speculating wildly):

```
4 bytes - global
4 bytes - N.data
4 bytes - N.c_data
```

where the alignment is adjusted to suit the CPU. The cache will just mirror RAM, nothing is "moved around to suit alignment" - the alignment will already have been taken care of when the variables were allocated in RAM.

This whole chunk may then potentially get read into the cache as one.

Comment: Based on your answer, I modified the question to keep global and N as local variables. Now my question is, whether the address of either global or N on the cachleline will be a offset which multiple of 4? like 0,4,8 . OR can it start at offset 3 , 5 on the cacheline? May be I am missing architecture knowledge here. please guide as to how data is pulled in and stored in cache from a alignment perspective.

Comment: @AnupBuchke The variables will be aligned if the compiler/linker put them at aligned addresses in RAM to begin with. The cache is just an identical copy of the RAM, containing 0 to _n_ bytes of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps. I will lookup how linker puts them in RAM.